# Ignoring numbers with letters around them

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
  const char *str = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  getline(&str,&len,stdin);
  int i = 0;
  unsigned int count = 0, tmp = 0;

  printf("%s\n", str);

  while (sscanf(&str[count], "%d %n", &i, &tmp) != EOF) {
    count += tmp;
    printf("number %d\n", i);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is ask the user for a line of integers (positive or negative) and I only care about integers that are valid that have a space between them, if there was a non numeric char entered then it should ignore what comes after it. Up top is what I have so far but I have some bugs with it, what I have right now is also ignoring white space which is what I want. Look at EXP for more clarification.

```
EXP: 
input: 1 2 3 4a              desired output-> 1 2 3    my ouput-> 1 2 3 4 4  
input: 1 2 3 a4              desired output-> 1 2 3    my ouput-> 1 2 3 3
input: 1 2 3 a b c 4 5 6 7   desired output-> 1 2 3    my output-> 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 7 
Valid input EXP:
input:    12                   367 98 -3 -67      desired output-> 12 367 98 -3 -67
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! So basically you want to extract all of the integer numbers in the string and put them in an integer array?

Comment: I was gonna put them into a linked list, but for simplicity sake lets say array.

Comment: Reading a line at a time is the correct approach, but for conversion, `strtol()` is the proper tool, utilizing the `endptr` parameter to determine if any non-digit or non-whitespace character remains after conversion. You can use `sscanf()` with `%n` to scan forward from `str + count + n` to check of non-digit/non-whitespace characters.

Comment: Hmm ok. I will try something using strtol() instead, it looks to be the easier way to do it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need to work through a buffer picking out numeric values, you want to think `strtoX()` (where `X` can be `l`, `ul`, `f`, `d`, for `strtol()`, etc..) The reason being is two-fold. (1) these functions were designed to allow you to do that by providing parameters of a pointer to the string itself, and the `endptr` parameter that is updated to point to the next character after the last digit successfully converted; and (2) these function provide complete error detection for all aspects of the conversion.

By virtue of the `endptr` parameter being updated to one-past the last digit converted, you simply loop through your buffer, attempting the conversion, and upon successfully conversion, you just update the the initial pointer to `endptr` and repeat until you run out of characters. See [man 3 strtol](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html)

Since `endptr` is updated to point one-past the last digit converted, you can simply check whether the character pointed to be `endptr` is either the *nul-terminating* character for the string or `!isspace(*endptr)` to determine if a non-digit was included in that group of numbers.

A simple implementation for your case would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAXC 1024

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char buf[MAXC];     /* buffer to hold each line */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    
    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {             /* read each line into buf */
        char *p = buf, *ep = p;                 /* pointers to use with strtol() */
        for (;;) {                              /* loop continually */
            errno = 0;                          /* reset errno */
            long val = strtol (p, &ep, 0);      /* attempt conversion to long */
            if (p == ep)                        /* check if no characters converted */
                break;
            else if (errno)                     /* check for under/overflow */
                break;
            else if (*ep && !isspace(*ep))      /* check next char for non-space */
                break;
            else
                printf (" %ld", val);           /* good all-digit conversion */
            
            p = ep;                             /* update pointer to endpointer */
        }
        putchar ('\n');                         /* tidy up with newline */
    }
    
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/numwalpha.txt
1 2 3 4a
1 2 3 a4
1 2 3 a b c 4 5 6 7
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtol_numonly dat/numwalpha.txt
 1 2 3
 1 2 3
 1 2 3
```

**Adding Error Reporting**

On failure, you can simply output the characters beginning at `endptr` (`ep` above) to see why things failed. You can include a preprocessor directive to turn the error reporting on/off by using a `DEBUG` define if you like, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAXC 1024

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char buf[MAXC];     /* buffer to hold each line */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    
    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {             /* read each line into buf */
        char *p = buf, *ep = p;                 /* pointers to use with strtol() */
        for (;;) {                              /* loop continually */
            errno = 0;                          /* reset errno */
            long val = strtol (p, &ep, 0);      /* attempt conversion to long */
            if (p == ep) {                      /* check if no characters converted */
#ifdef DEBUG
                fprintf (stderr, "error: no digits converted in '%s'.\n", p);
#endif
                break;
            }
            else if (errno) {                   /* check for under/overflow */
#ifdef DEBUG
                fprintf (stderr, "error: over/under-flow in conversion or '%s'.\n", p);
#endif
                break;
            }
            else if (*ep && !isspace(*ep)) {    /* check next char for non-space */
#ifdef DEBUG
                fprintf (stderr, "error: mixed alphanumeric '%s'.\n", ep);
#endif
                break;
            }
            else
                printf (" %ld", val);           /* good all-digit conversion */
            
            p = ep;                             /* update pointer to endpointer */
        }
        putchar ('\n');                         /* tidy up with newline */
    }
    
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

Then compiled with `-DDEBUG` to enable the define, you would have:

```
$ ./bin/strtol_numonly dat/numwalpha.txt
error: mixed alphanumeric 'a
'.
 1 2 3
error: no digits converted in ' a4
'.
 1 2 3
error: no digits converted in ' a b c 4 5 6 7
'.
 1 2 3
```

Which shows the first case failed due to an `'a'` at the end, the second due to an `"a4"` as the string to be converted, and the last because `"a b c 4 5 6 7"` was all that was left in the string, with `'a'` being the next conversion.